# Displaying video files in React Native Image component

Tags: react-native

I'd like to show a list with image and video files from cameraroll in React Native app. I (accidentally) have seen that the Image component can display probably the first frame of a mov file on iOS. I checked the documentation but they write nothing about video files.

> A React component for displaying different types of images, including
>   network images, static resources, temporary local images, and images
>   from local disk, such as the camera roll.

My question is if it's good practice to use the Image component for displaying a "thumbnail" from a video file this way or is it better to store a separate thumbnail (image file) for every video and display those in the list instead?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to figure out the path of the video so I can upload it.

Comment: @Keng Not really. I use the Image component today and I haven't noticed some  performance issues yet but I usually don't have so many videos in the list when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this feature when we store '.mp4'(from local storage) in an image component, it can works as thumbnail without degradation in performance. However, I also noticed when you try to render any network video file it doesn't seem to work that way.

So this feature only works when we are displaying videos from phone's gallery.

Therefore, it is good to maintain thumbnails for video files if you are using videos from any other resource